Do I start another question replacing "making out" with "having sex"?
This is about Is it legal to photograph a couple making out in a cinema?
I originally meant to ask if the couple are having sex in the cinema, which is why the link says "having sex". I used "making out" because I was unaware that making out does not imply sex. I realized it doesn't when phoog wrote his/her comment, so I updated the question. Dale M reverted without giving a reason. I reverted again, and he timed me out. The suspension message said not to change questions after answers have been written. This suggests that if the question really is about whether the couple are having sex, I should ask it separately.
However I suspect the answer will be very similar, and it's quite possible such a question will be marked as a duplicate. Therefore I am asking it here: do I actually ask the same question verbatim, with "making out" replaced by "having sex", separately?

This would be tricky in a general situation; in this situation I don't see how changing that nuance would produce different answers since both of the existing answers address the full spectrum of intimate activity.

@feetwet are you saying Dale M was incorrect to revert my change?

@Allure No, I'm saying – given the answers you already have – I don't see why you think you would get different answers if you made the change.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

One option is to offer a bounty to reward any answerer who would take a slight tangent and answer your closely related question.
I've seen this done where someone wants to attract an answer from a specific jurisdiction that wasn't targeted by the original question and answers.
